# I can't understand what means this line?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, I have some code to debug, everything is clear except one instruction which is:

```
double insuranceID = -0x2f2f2f2f;
```

thanks,

Comment: Hexadecimal literal.

Comment: Variable `insuranceID` is set to a hex value `-0x2f2f2f2f`. What is unclear?

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? It's not something easily google-able and the term is easy for anybody to explain to OP

Comment: @tinkertime He had to read at least about the basics of language

Comment: hexadecimal double notation definitely not where i'm recommending to a newb to start reading about in their first c++ book

Comment: @ Michael O the unclear is to me that I am new to c++ I wasn't sure if it is hex or something related to pointers

Comment: I know also it's stupid question but as @tinkertime said I googled and I couldn't found something sure

Comment: It's unusual to find this in production code. If `-0x2f2f2f2f` was assigned to an int it likely would be some sort of "magic" number not otherwise used possibly designed to indicate something hadn't been initialized. This isn't good coding technique but has been done a lot years ago. However, assigning a hex literal to a double is quite strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preceding negative sign means the value is negative.

The prefix **0x** means what comes after is an hexadecimal value.

In other words, in your question  **-0x2f2f2f2f** in hex is **-791621423** in decimal

Comment: With pleasure, glad the explanation cleared things up. Good luck in your learning of C++

Answer (score 5):

When you don't understand some code, it helps to simplify it as much as you need to until it makes sense to you.

You could simplify that line to:

```
int i1 = 0x2f2f2f2f;
int i2 = -i1;
double insuranceID = i2;
```

and output the data to make sure it makes sense.

```
std::cout << i1 << " " << i2 << " " << insuranceID << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes now I see what should I done